# Why isn't CSS stylizing SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image embedded in an object tag that I'm trying to stylize with CSS. The SVG is displaying on the page but changes in the CSS do nothing. I figure I probably have a problem with how I'm linking the CSS with the HTML. I don't want to link the CSS internally in the HTML. Why does the SVG not inherit the CSS styling?

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesheet_svg.css" ?>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topheading">
        <div id="logobox">
            <object class="logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="Wolf_template_empty.svg"><img id="logocenter" data="Wolf_template_empty.gif" /></object>
        </div>
        <h1 id="ip"></h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
.logo {
stroke: #006600;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stroke is not a valid CSS property for the `<object>` tag. If you want your SVG file to reference external CSS then you have to add a reference to an external CSS file specifying stroke within your SVG file. You don't provide source for your SVG, so I don't know whether you've tried to do that or not.

Comment: I thought I could reference an SVG image directly in an object tag within the HTML to a CSS file. Can you show me an example of the SVG file?

Comment: It took me awhile to understand what you were talking about but I looked at the website I was using as a reference and I eventually understood. I didn't know that I had to reference from within the picture itself. I finally got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason CSS styles don't penetrate into `iframe`s. That is, it's in a different sort of context, and if you want the styles in the page to affect it, you have to embed the SVG directly on the page. You could alternatively add the CSS into the SVG, where it will affect the SVG (but not the HTML).

Comment: The following websites say it can be done, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/, http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/scalable-vector-graphic-css-styling/

Comment: @user3304179 From that document "The problem with both <img> and background-image... Is that you don't get to control the innards of the SVG with CSS like you can with the following two ways."

Comment: From that document: "If "inline" SVG just isn't your jam (remember it does have some legit drawbacks like being hard to cache), **you can link to an SVG file and retain the ability to affect its parts with CSS by using <object>.**"
"**SVG has a way to declare an external stylesheet, which can be nice for authoring and caching and whatnot.** This only works with <object> embedding of SVG files as far as I've tested. You'll need to put this in the SVG file above the opening <svg> tag." Other websites also say it can be done.

Comment: @user3304179  The CSS file has to be referenced from *inside* the SVG file, you can't affect an `<object>` with the CSS from the main webpage.

Comment: How do I reference to the CSS file from inside the SVG?

Comment: @user3304179: Using the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction. See [the relevant portion of the SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#ReferencingExternalStyleSheets) and [the standard it references](http://www.w3.org/1999/06/REC-xml-stylesheet-19990629/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're limited when it comes to styling an image in CSS. You'd be better off making your change in Illustrator or Photoshop. If you save an image with a transparent background you can add a background color to the image. Other than that, positioning is the only other way to manipulate an image with CSS. Check out this article for a reference - http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/.

Comment: I already referenced this website in one of my comments. It shows him using CSS to stylize the SVG. I am especially interested in using this with the :hover property like the guy uses in his example and I can't change that directly in Photoshop. This can't be done with a normal image with java which I want to avoid.